# How to compare Command Line Arguments in C like in C++

Tags: c

Normally in C++ I would compare command line options as follows:

```
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (std::string(argv[1]) == "-h") /*Handle -h option*/
  return 0;
}
```

This works just fine. But is there a way to do something similar in C?

Comment: `if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) { /*whatever*/ }`

Comment: You're looking for [`strcmp`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

Comment: One of you please create an answer.

Comment: In C++ I often write `std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc)`. That converts them all to strings so you don't need to do it on a case by case basis.

Comment: Consider using `getopt()` to process command line options instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is just your code converted to C. As C doesn't have the type std::string you have to use character arrays. Those are compared with strcmp.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) /*Handle -h option*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This gives me SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `#include <string.h>` and use `strcmp()` as in

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0) {
    // whatever
}
```

Or, if you prefer to do it "by hand" with no calls into the C standard library

```
if ((argv[1][0] == '-') && (argv[1][1] == 'h') && (argv[1][2] == '\0')) {
    // whatever
}
```